# Calculate EMI based on principal, rate, duration (month or years)

Tags: python, calculator, finance

I am trying to create an EMI calculator for a loan. The problem description is:

> Given a principal amount, rate of interest, monthly or quarterly installment terms and duration of loan in months/years and print EMI amount.
> Input format:Principal, Rate of Interest per year, M/Q for Monthly or quarterly installment, duration of year in Year (Y) or Month (M)
> Example Inputs:
>
> 10000, 12, M, 2Y: Principal = 10000, Rate of Interest = 12%, Monthly installment, Duration = 2 years
>
> 50000, 10.5, Q, 36M: Principal = 50000, Rate of Interest = 10.5%, Quarterly installment, Duration = 36 months

What are the flaws in this code? How can I perfect it?

```
def EMI_calculator(P,R , M,d):
#set rate of interest monthly
    print type(R)
    r= (R/(12.0 *100))
    print r
#chechk if monthly or quaterly installment
    if M== 'Q': 
        x=4
    else:
        x=1

    if d[-1] =='Y':
        print "duration in years"
        n = d[0:(len(d)-1)]
        print n
        m = 12 *int(n)
        print m
    elif d[-1] =='M':
        print "duration is in months"
        n = d[0:(len(d)-1)]
        print n   
        m = 1 *int(n) 
        print m
             
    EMI = x*(P*r*(1+r)**m)//((1+r)**m - 1)
    return EMI


print EMI_calculator(10000,12,'Q','3Y')
```

Comment: Can you specify what EMI is and how it should be calculated, besides in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments to your other questions some things were mentioned that are also applicable to this question as well, like:

1. Try to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.
2. Single letter names should be avoided.
3. Avoid useless comments, make your code self explanatory.
4. Check for invalid input, raise exceptions.

Now, you have some [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) like `12`, `100` and `4`. Give them names. Make them constants. Don't leave them like that.

Some prints don't make a lot of sense, like printing type of `R` or printing if duration is in years or in months. That looks more like information for debugging. I suggest you to take a look at [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) module and give it a try. But for such a small program it is probably an overkill.

This `n = d[0:(len(d)-1)]` is repeated twice in your code and it can be taken out of that `if-elif` statement. Moreover it can be simplified as `n = d[:-1]`.

Instead of writing

```py
EMI = x*(P*r*(1+r)**m)//((1+r)**m - 1)
return EMI
```

you can write just

```
return x*(P*r*(1+r)**m)//((1+r)**m - 1)
```

Finally, wrap your `print EMI_calculator(10000,12,'Q','3Y')` like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print EMI_calculator(10000, 12, 'Q', '3Y')
```

You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).